# VBA32 claims that FlashDevelop is suspected of ZIP.MailBomb

Tags: flashdevelop, malware, virus, false-positive

I just downloaded FlashDevelop from [flashdevelop.org](http://flashdevelop.org) and uploaded it to Virustotal. Here are the [results](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/4901008948a47a5bad456eae6bbe230384b7a7b5d9d16064ae3b18137b94421d/analysis/).

As you can see, VBA32 claims that the file is "suspected of ZIP.MailBomb".

What does it mean ?
Can I safely install FlashDevelop on my PC ?

Answer (score 0):

Heres FlashDevelop 5.1.1 running on my pc: https://gyazo.com/715e4bad49b8c5c8ad2e86d9aea0f968, I've had it since I installed this pc and it doesn't look like it is harmful.

It's most likely a false positive and yes you can safely install flashdevelop (5.1.1) on your pc assuming that it is a legit copy of it.